# dotnet hotchocolate. if I use Projection do I need to use DataLoader?

Tags: .net, graphql, projection, dataloader

UserType:

```
[Node(IdField = nameof(Id))]
public class UserType
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public Company? Company { get; set; }

    [NodeResolver]
    public static async Task<UserType> GetUser(
        Guid id,
        UserByIdDataLoader userById,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken,
        [Service] IMapper mapper)
        => mapper.Map<Data.User, UserType>(await userById.LoadAsync(id,cancellationToken));
    
}
```

Query:

```
[UseApplicationDbContext]
    [UsePaging]
    [UseProjection]
    [UseFiltering]
    public IQueryable<UserType> GetUsers(
        [ScopedService] ApplicationDbContext dbContext,
        [Service] IMapper mapper)
    {
        return mapper.ProjectTo<UserType>(
            dbContext.Users.AsNoTracking());
    }
```

if I run this query:

```
users(first:4){
  edges{
    node{
      id
      company{
        companyName
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

it will run db query like this

```sql
SELECT `t`.`Id`, `c`.`Id` IS NOT NULL, `c`.`CompanyName`
FROM (
    SELECT `a`.`Id`
    FROM `AspNetUsers` AS `a`
    LIMIT @__p_0
) AS `t`
LEFT JOIN `Companies` AS `c` ON `t`.`Id` = `c`.`UserId`
```

if I use dataloader for get company. it will get all of property of Company(*can not use projection to dataloader).

so, if I use projection is there any performance problem even if I don't use dataloader?